# Sending variable by ajax in use of laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to send two variables through ajax into the php script in laravel.
It is actually not clear to me how to move these variables.
Would you mind guys to give me some advice on it? the newComment contains some string, and id is just a number.

```
var newComment =  document.getElementById('newComment').value;               

                  $.ajax({
                      type: 'get',
                      url: '/editcomment',
                      data: {newComment: newComment,
                                     id: id},

                      success:function(){
                               alert('success');
                             },
                      error:function(){
                               alert('failure');
                             }
                  });                     
              });
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::any('/editcomment/{id}/{newComment}', 'HomeController@editComment');
```

And here goes the function in homecontroller:

```
public function editComment(){
    $aaa = Input::all();
    return $aaa;
    }
```

I am struggling with this for last 2 days, constantly looking at documentations and tutorials but have no idea how to do this.

Comment: for debugging purposes use `dd();` in your case `dd(Input::all());`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add the variables to the url for this request. The data you include in your ajax request will be send to the server as a post body.

Try changing the route to `Route::any('/editcomment', 'HomeController@editComment');`

And use

```
public function editComment(){
    return Input::all();
}
```

This should display the `id` and the `newComment`

Comment: Thank you! Should the returned variable for example "return $variable = Input::all()" be available back in the first ajax script? It says it doesnt know the variable when im doing alert(variable)

Comment: Now you are mixing server side and client side code. You cannot mix php code and javascript code, it is impossible.
If you want to send data back to the webpage I suggest you create a json string and send this to the client. Javascript can easily parse this.

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your route file like this :
`Route::any('/editcomment', 'HomeController@editComment');` because yo dont need to ajax request parameter to send in route file.

And yes in your controller method `editComment` change like this:

```
    public function editComment(){
         if(Request::ajax()) {
                return Input::all();
           }
}
```

We have to check that requested by ajax call.

Comment: Thank you! Should the returned variable for example "return $variable = Input::all()" be available back in the first ajax script? It says it doesnt know the variable when im doing alert(variable)

Comment: yes offcourse in success portion in ajax call. alert('data); what you get or see in inspect element in XHR request

Comment: just try $comment = Input::get("newComment ");

Answer (score 0):

Try, 
`$_GET['newComment']` and `$_GET['id']`. This will work.

Thank you :)